# Show only 2 softwares for each category

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I have a table software (id_software, software_name, category)

What SQL query to show only 2 software for each category ?

For example I want to get :

```
 |id_software | software_name | category|
-+------------+---------------+---------+-
 |          1 | Photoshop     | 5       |
 |          2 | illustrator   | 5       |
 |          3 | Firefox       | 1       |
 |          4 | I.E           | 1       |
-+--------------------------------------+-
```

Comment: could you post your sample data for this?

Comment: hello Saechel,
The table software contains only 3 fields (id_software, software_name,  category) and I want to show only 2 rows for each category

Comment: quel SQL encore? [mysql|sql|sql-sewer|oracle|postgresql]

Comment: @wildplasser, pardon ? je n'ai pas compris
J'ai mis tout ces tags pour plus de visibilité, de toute façon la syntaxe on s'en fou j'ai besoin de connaitre le raisonnement

Comment: Bien sur!: [in short]Your question is too broad. ALSO: show some effort; since it looks trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
(select *
from table1 n
where
( select count(*)
from table1 m
where n.categorie = m.categorie
and n.id_software <= m.id_software) <= 2
order by n.id_software, n.id_software desc) as tn
```

Source: http://mindbuffer.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/mysql-get-the-top-2-rows-for-each-category-with-certain-condition/

Comment: If this one worked for you, why did't you give your accepted mark in this answer instead of the other one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the row_number function for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
     (SELECT 
          Category,
          id_software,
          software_name,
          [Nth_Software] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by Category ORDER BY Id_software)
     FROM
          table
      ) T
WHERE
     T.Nth_Software <=2
```

This gives you the first two software entries based on softwareId for every category.

Comment: You should have added that this is SQL Server/T-SQL syntax only (the `[...] ` quoting and the "assignment" operator in a column)